# Using NGINX to reverse proxy traffic to a non-standard prefix

Tags: azure, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, azure-analysis-services

I am trying to use nginx to reverse proxy to a URL

> asazure://aspaaseastus2.asazure.windows.net/aas1

the protocol asazure is indeed https but it can't be https in the config.

Something to the effect of:

```
server_name example.com;
        ssl on;

        location /aas1 {

            proxy_pass asazure://aspaaseastus.asazure.windows.net/aas1;
        }
```

But this is giving me the following error:

> nginx: [emerg] invalid URL prefix in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

### Background:

I am trying to reverse proxy traffic to an Azure Analysis Services instance. The AAS only accepts traffic from internal IP addresses, so I am thinking if I can put a reverse proxy in the internal network and connect forward to the AAS it should work.

I need to connect to the AAS using a Microsoft SSMS.